# I expose my pod in kubernetes but I can´t seem to establish a connection with it

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

I am trying to expose a deployment I made on minikube:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: deployment-test
  labels:
    app: debian
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: debian
  strategy: {}
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: debian
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: agracia10/debian_bash:latest
        name: debian
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8006
        resources: {}
      restartPolicy: Always
status: {}
```

I decided to follow was is written on [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46245508/how-create-service-on-minikube-with-yaml-configuration-which-accessible-from-hos)

I try to expose the deployment using the following command:

```
kubectl expose pod deployment-test-8497d6f458-xxhgm --type=NodePort --port=8080 --target-port=80
```

but when I try to then access the service created by the expose command, using the url provided by

```
minikube service deployment-test-8497d6f458-xxhgm --url
```

it throws an error using packetsender to try and connect to the service:
[packet sender log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/df275.png)

Im not really sure what the reason for this could be, I think it has something to do with the fact that when I get the services it says  on the external ip field. Also, when I try and retrieve the node IP using `minikube ip` it gives an address, but when the `minikube service --url` it gives the 127.0.0.1 address. In any case, using either one does not work.

Comment: do you have created a service for your deployment?

Comment: target-port and container-port should match.  Confirm that the containerport is actually 8006 and if so, change the following kubectl expose pod deployment-test-8497d6f458-xxhgm --type=NodePort --port=8080 --target-port=8006

Answer (score 2):

it's not working due to a port configuration mismatch.

You deployment container running on the `8006` but you have exposed the `8080` and your target port is : `--target-port=80`

so due to this it's not working.

Ideal flow of traffic goes like :

```
service (node port, cluster IP or any) > Deployment > PODs
```

Below sharing the example for deployment and service

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: blog-app-server-instance
  labels:
    app: blog-app
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: blog-app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: blog-app
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: agracia10/debian_bash:latest
        image: blog-app-server
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8006
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: blog-app-service
  labels:
    app: blog-app
spec:
  selector:
    app: blog-app
  type: NodePort
  ports:
  - port: 80
    nodePort: 31364
    targetPort: 8006
    protocol: TCP
    name: HTTP
```

so things I have changed are `image` and `target port`.

Once your Node port service is up and running you will send the request on Port **80** or **31364**

i will redirect the request internally to the target port which is **8006** for the container also.

Using this command you exposed your deployment on wrong target point

```
kubectl expose pod deployment-test-8497d6f458-xxhgm --type=NodePort --port=8080 --target-port=80
```

ideally it should be **8006**

Comment: I followed your explanation but I still can not seem to access the pod.

Comment: please the details like error you are getting or something like that, to debug you can also use the port forwarding.

Comment: I dont really see an error in kubernetes per se. the thing is i am trying to connect with packet sender, I try and access the service created with the minikube ip ip and the targetport but it shows in packet sender that it cant connect and im not sure why. if it helps, the minikube service shows a different ip and port number for that service.

Answer (score 0):

As I know the simplest way to expose the deployment to service we can run this command, you don't expose the pod but expose the deployment.

```
kubectl expose deployment deployment-test --port 80
```